# Tags for each algorithm (GMRES, MINRES, ERK, IRK, BDF, ...)?

Tags: discussion

Should we allow tags for each and every different method/algorithm? Or should these be combined in topical tags like "iterative methods"? I'm a bit afraid that many tags will only be used in a single question. For example, I noticed that there are already tags "minres", "qmr", ...

Answer (score 2):

For reference, the tags were cleaned up on March 29th. See [Request for Comment: Tag clean-up](https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/q/237/276) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

No, we shouldn't.  Please mention any tags you have encountered that you think should be deleted/removed, and Geoff and I will go through the list on Sunday and remove them.  You can also suggest that a tag be merged into another tag if you think it is too specific (and there is a more general tag to catch it with).

Comment: ok. I'll see if I can find some time before Sunday. Is there any quick & dirty way to get a dump of all tags? What's the best way to communicate with you guys?

Comment: with a little parsing, you can get them from [1,](http://api.scicomp.stackexchange.com/1.1/tags?pagesize=100&page=1) [2](http://api.scicomp.stackexchange.com/1.1/tags?pagesize=100&page=2), and [3](http://api.scicomp.stackexchange.com/1.1/tags?pagesize=100&page=3).

Comment: You can either open meta questions (which pings the moderators) as well as leave a message in the [SciComp Chat Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1878/computational-science), which Geoff and I also try to keep an eye on.

Comment: @GertVdE: Aron and I have talked about this issue in person, and my position can be found [here](http://meta.scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/228/276) on an answer to another tag question in Meta. I support the consolidation of singleton tags; we should only have tags for each algorithm when such tags can support at least 5-10 questions, and the question is specific only to a single algorithm, because there is a 5 tag per question limit.

Comment: @Geoff: I've gone through all tags indicating which ones to keep, rename, merge (according to my gut feeling, of course). I've made a table of this. How do I get it to you both?