# Replace 'numerics' tag

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

I would like to see the [numerics](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/numerics) tag replaced, because

- it 'works' only because of a mutual misunderstanding. As for science, 'Numerics' refers to the investigation of numeric patterns. The first search result in Wikipedia, that bears numerics in its title, is [bible numerics](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=numerics+&title=Special:Search&fulltext=1)
- the way it is used, it is not specific. SciComp itself already is about numerical approaches in sciences. Cf. also the tag wiki: "Questions on the aspects of numerical methods/analysis relevant to scientific computing."
- if it is used to direct to theoretical results, [numerical-analysis](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/numerical-analysis) would be the right tag
- if it is used to direct to numerical methods, there are more specific tags like [iterative-solver](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iterative-solver) or [finite-elements](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finite-elements).

So the question is: Is there a need to do such a global replacement and, if there was an agreement on this, how to do this best?

Comment: Sounds good to me. Any other thoughts for or against? Based on the question, it looks like the retagging will have to be done on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: Let's deal with [tag:numerical] too, while we're at it...

Comment: Of the 150 questions tagged 'numerics', there is only a handful for which this is the only tag. The remaining questions have more specific tags and hence can have 'numerics' removed without loss. The manual effort would therefore be relatively small.

Comment: Looking at the questions, it seems that [tag:numerics] and (to a lesser extent) [tag:numerical] is often used for classical numerical analysis (in the sense of numerical methods for classical calculus problems such as differentiation, not analysis of numerical methods), because there doesn't seem to be a suitable tag (or tags) for that.

Comment: Now, I have also browsed some more questions. It looks like in most cases, the 'numerics' or 'numerical' tag can be simply removed. But I also think there should be a general classification for things related to classical numerical analysis courses as @ChristianClason has pointed out.

Comment: I have updated the question, so that it admits an answer.

Comment: Agree. Close to half of the recently active questions share the `numerics` tag, despite covering a wide range of topics. The presence of the tag on a question offers very little insight.

Comment: I have taken the opportunity of [this question](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/7456/how-should-non-constant-coefficients-be-treated-with-finite-volume-first-order-u) to create the 'numerical-analysis' tag, since it is a generic example for numerical analysis.

Comment: Sounds good to me as well.

Comment: @Jan Hi, Jan I suggest you make a poll in the answer section for the question like here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4752/exposure-of-new-questions-poll-on-browsing-habits Then we can just casting votes on each

Comment: @AronAhmadia For I haven't reached enough reputation to tag synonyms on this SE site, I believe tagging [tag:numerics] as a synonym of [tag:numerical-analysis] is one way as well...

Comment: To me *numerics* sounds like it's a false-friend translation of the German "Numerik", which is used as a synonim of "numerische Mathematik" ([example ref](https://www.uni-ulm.de/mawi/institut-fuer-numerische-mathematik/institut/was-ist-numerik/)).

Answer (score 3):

I'm answering to bump up this thread. 7 years later, that tag is still there.

Comment: What is your preference?  We could replace the tag or just drop it if it carries little information on our site.  On a slightly broader topic, we should [probably have an annual thread](https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237/request-for-comment-tag-clean-up) on "tag maintenance" that would more aggressively tackle these tasks.

Comment: @hardmath I would just drop it, personally.

Comment: For reference here is the current year [tag management thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31103/tag-management-2020) on Math.SE.  Suggestions are posted as "answers" and upvoted/downvoted accordingly as users agree or disagree.

Answer (score 3):

Bringing this back up, [numerics](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/numerics) and [numerical-modeling](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/numerical-modeling) are two of the most used tags on the site. I see a couple issues with this:

1. Neither tag has a tag wiki or usage guidelines, so they have taken on a pretty wide scope.
2. Off hand, its not clear to me what the difference in scope between the two tags (again, no usage guidelines).

I'm open to suggestions, but my thought process for fixing this would be:

1. Make [numerics](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/numerics) a synonym of [numerical-modeling](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/numerical-modeling). I think numerical modeling is at least a little less opaque of a description of the types of questions asked.
2. Add usage guidelines to [numerical-modeling](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/numerical-modeling) to make its scope clearer/narrower.
3. Over time, prune [numerical-modeling](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/numerical-modeling) from questions where it isn't needed or where a more specific tag could be added. This step isn't crucial, as adding the tag usage will make it more useful on the questions its already on.

Comment: Just checking in to see if your suggestions got implemented.  I'm a bit shy of the edit-tag-wiki privilege, but [tag:numerics] and [tag:numerical-modeling] still lack a wiki.  According to current tag-info, both numerical-modeling and numerical are mapped to numerics, unlike what you envisioned.